# Including the iterator in numpy sum function

Tags: python, numpy, sum

So I have the following function

```
def get_a(x):
    start = timer()
    A = np.zeros(len(x))
    for k in range(len(x)):
        Ak = 0
        Ak = np.sum(x*np.exp(-2j*pi*(k*1/len(x))))
        # for i in range(len(x)):
            # Ak+= x[i]*np.exp(-2j*pi*(k*i/len(x)))
        Ak = norm(Ak)
        A[k] = Ak
        
    end = timer()
    print(end - start) 
    return A
```

The commented part of the function is what I want to actually do, but it takes way too much time iterating over the array instead of using numpy's sum function, but the problem is that I need to somehow access the "i" value of the sum. In the line

```
Ak = np.sum(x*np.exp(-2j*pi*(k*1/len(x))))
```

What I need to replace is the "1" for the sum index. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the arrays mentioned are rank 1, you can produce a numpy array of the appropriate length with [`numpy.arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html). Consider

```
Ak = np.sum(x*np.exp(-2j*pi*(k*np.arange(len(x))/len(x))))
```

There's some more refactoring that can be done. In particular, the whole fraction  in the exponent can be replaced with an appropriate [`numpy.linspace`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) call to get the appropriate ranges, but that should get you started vectorizing your equation.

Comment: Thank you, it runs extremely fast now. I will check np's linspace aswell!